# What is "Java Number Types"

Tags: java

I'm starting to learn java and reading a book about JAVA. Thet keep referring to "Java Number Types" but at the same time they are mentioning strings and chars.

Which are the "Java Number Types"? Since char can produce numbers is it a Number type?

regards

Comment: Doesn’t that book give a definition (when you search hard enough, for example where the concept was introduced)? They should know better than we what they mean by it.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-4.html#jls-NumericType):

> The numeric types are the integral types and the floating-point types.
>
> The integral types are byte, short, int, and long, whose values are 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit and 64-bit signed two's-complement integers, respectively, and char, whose values are 16-bit unsigned integers representing UTF-16 code units (§3.1).
>
> The floating-point types are float, whose values include the 32-bit IEEE 754 floating-point numbers, and double, whose values include the 64-bit IEEE 754 floating-point numbers.

So yes, `char` is included.

What the book means by that is anyone's guess, especially without knowing what book it is.

Answer (score 1):

See the docs for the [Number](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) interface.

> The abstract class Number is ... numeric values that are convertible to the primitive types byte, double, float, int, long, and short.

So, essentially, almost anything that is *like a number*.

Includes (but not limited to):

> AtomicInteger, AtomicLong, BigDecimal, BigInteger, Byte, Double, DoubleAccumulator, DoubleAdder, Float, Integer, Long, LongAccumulator, LongAdder, Short

Comment: This is the only deep Java answer at the momemnt

Comment: A person who is just getting started with Java, probably cant get much out of reading interface doc

Answer (score 1):

Number types Contains following types

[image]